# SCNText getBoundingBoxMin:max: always zero

Tags: ios, iphone, scenekit, scnnode, scntext

I am trying to determine the bounding box of a `SCNText` but  `getBoundingBoxMin:max:` always gives me zero.

This is the code that runs inside a `SCNText` class extension, so `self` is the `[textNode geometry]`.

```
  [self setString:newText];
  SCNVector3 min = SCNVector3Zero;
  SCNVector3 max = SCNVector3Zero;

  SCNNode *textNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:self];
  [textNode getBoundingBoxMin:&min max:&max];

  CGSize sizeMax = CGSizeMake( max.x - min.x,
                               max.y - min.y);
```

I have also tried this

```
  [self setString:newText];
  SCNVector3 min = SCNVector3Zero;
  SCNVector3 max = SCNVector3Zero;

  [self getBoundingBoxMin:&min max:&max];

  CGSize sizeMax = CGSizeMake( max.x - min.x,
                               max.y - min.y);
```

`sizeMax` is always zero.

NOTE: I have discovered why the problem happens.

The problem happens when this adjust is called inside a block like this:

```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                 ^{                  });
```

so, If I call this code from the main thread, it **works**:

```
[self setString:newText];
SCNVector3 min = SCNVector3Zero;
SCNVector3 max = SCNVector3Zero;

SCNNode *textNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:self];
[textNode getBoundingBoxMin:&min max:&max];

CGSize sizeMax = CGSizeMake( max.x - min.x,
                             max.y - min.y);
```

but If I call this from another thread it will **not work**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
             ^{                
[self setString:newText];
SCNVector3 min = SCNVector3Zero;
SCNVector3 max = SCNVector3Zero;

SCNNode *textNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:self];
[textNode getBoundingBoxMin:&min max:&max];

CGSize sizeMax = CGSizeMake( max.x - min.x,
                             max.y - min.y);

});
```

the problem is that this block is called from a dispatch block, so I need to re-dispatch it to the main queue but doing that prevents the code from working. In theory dispatching a block to the main queue should be equivalent of running it from the main thread but apparently it is not.

Do you guys know any workaround?

Comment: does wrapping that in a `SCNTransaction` help? (set duration to 0, begin, commit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*from comment*

You can try to wrap that in a transaction:

```
[SCNTransaction begin];
[SCNTransaction setAnimationDuration:0];
...
[SCNTransaction commit];
```